# itextsharp advance pdf generation by configuration xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I am generating PDF using iTextSharp.i got so many sample code in google but how we can configure pdf setting which is required to generate PDF like

```
var doc = new Document(PageSize.A5);
```

var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(100f, 300f));

these all setting i wanted to set my config xml file and read xml and generate pdf on fly. is any professional sample example code available?plz help..

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? Why doesn't it work? Seems like you are asking for advice in general, whereas StackOverflow is meant for specific technical problems.

Comment: Ignoring iTextSharp for now, do you know how to read configuration information in ASP.Net in general?